# Datatable integration with Django

Tags: angularjs, django, datatable

I am new in web development so, I do not have any idea about how to use dataTable in a Django project.
I have `json` data and I want to display the data into a table using `DataTable`

Created a Django project and Django set up and all is working fine.
I look into some source but, couldn't find any blog or other website to integrating `DataTable` for **beginners**.

Answer (score 0):

Consider JQuery Datatables a "wrapper" for a good table experience.  If you want a good CRUD table experience (with AJAX) and json data, it's hard to beat Vitor Freitas' [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html) on the subject.  It may be a long tutorial, but the lessons you'll learn are invaluable and the result is applicable to many table use cases.

After that, making this (or any) table a datatable is fairly straightforward if you follow the [DataTables documentation.](https://datatables.net/)  Follow the "get started" guide.  The three basic steps are on the DataTables homepage.  If you're not too confident check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S7OFBY9atM&t=316s) by Yogi Coder, with a walk-through of each step.

Assuming you implement something like Vitor's tutorial linked above, then make the table a datatable, you may have a problem when you want to refresh your JQuery DataTable with new data upon the save/post.  To get past that, check out the answer on this post so you know how (and where) to "destroy" and re-initialize your table:

[DataTables Refresh Django Ajax Data on CRUD Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648408/datatables-refresh-django-ajax-data-on-crud-operations/60537782#60537782)

Good luck!